# Node.js ecmascript 6 mocking class methods

Tags: node.js

Can node.js ecmascript 6 features be used for mocking function calls ? I see there is `Proxy` but not sure how to use it.

Let say.. I have a code

```
class E{
  someOtherMethod(a){
    return 100;
  }
}
class D{
  someMethod(a){
    // some ... code 
    var e = new E();
    e.someOtherMethod();

    // some ... more code 
  }
}
```

**I want to mock it to when i have reference of just D and instance of E is created within someMethod**, that i want  to test.

```
var d = new D();
when(E).someOtherMethod(a).return(1); // Or anything similar with ES 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it out.

It should work mind you. ES6 doesn't change the internals of Javascript, it just puts some syntactic sugar on top of it. Here is the code I just tested out in Chrome (and it works by returning 'Mock'), so it should work fine without the function wrapper in Node.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    class D {
        someMethod() {
            return 100;
        }
    };

    var obj = new D();
    var oldMthd = obj.someMethod;
    obj.someMethod = function() { return 'Mock'; }
    alert(obj.someMethod());
})();
```

Comment: nice .. clarified my problem.. lets say.. want to mock E.someOtherrMethod() from D.someMethod where i don't have reference of instance of E.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You have access to E, but not to the instance? How could you mock it?

Comment: right,, like E is like DB .. i have access to wrapping class but not DB,, DB is called internally

Comment: The right think to do would probably be to change your approach to allow injection of the instance of E, or to allow the injection of a Builder of E. Then, you could easily mock it. Otherwise, your mock method could technically mock E the same way we mocked D, but that can get complex really fast.